# Dropbox Saver / Chooser drop-in with PhoneGap / Cordova or Sencha Touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, dropbox-api

I'm trying to integrate the new dropins inside a Sencha Touch application and so I follow the tutorial on dropbox api documentation.

Integration instructions seems as simple as this :

- Add the script to their API in the index.html, before my app script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/1/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="my_api_key">
```

- Create a simple Sencha component with the a tag in it, for instance :

```
{
    xtype: 'field',
    label: 'Dropbox',
    html: '<a href="res/icons/icon-64.png" class="dropbox-saver dropbox-dropin-btn dropbox-dropin-default"><span class="dropin-btn-status"></span>Save to dropbox</a>'
}
```

This will render as the desired dropbox button, however, clicking on it either does nothing or simply displays the icon from the href. I know this has to do with the fact that i'm suppose to put a url to the file but I don't see what to put in there, as my app is gonna be wrapped with phonegap and deployed on a phone...

I can see several options though :

- Use a **webserver** : upload my local file to it, send back the url and pass this url to dropbox button
- Use a **complete url** starting with file:// but I think it won't work as you need to register an app on the dropbox console, with a domain name.
- Maybe I could use the **HTML5 File API** somehow to pass an absolute url, but i'm not really confident about this one either
- Choose **another dropbox API** which would be better suited for the task ? Maybe sync
- Use the **Phonegap sync plugin**, which is not mature I think, and as only iOS and Android support
- Another solution ?

Any tips or pointer to get this integration to work would be great.

Comment: hi there, what was the final solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that the Dropbox Saver works is that Dropbox fetches the content from a URL and stores it in the user's Dropbox. So the URL has to be a publicly accessible URL that Dropbox's servers can reach. (A `file://` URL won't work, since Dropbox won't be able to fetch the content.)

For now, you'll have to use a different API to store something in Dropbox, but this will require that the user authorize your app via OAuth. I'd suggest the JavaScript SDK: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js.

Comment: Yeah I saw this API but I was hoping it wouldn't be the answer. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question if you want Saver or Chooser, but there is now a Dropbox Chooser Phonegap plugin on Github:

https://github.com/cv-library/phonegap-plugin-dropbox-chooser

(Disclosure: I helped write it.)

Comment: But how can I use response? 
My app tries to download choosed file but Dropbox server replies (of course) 403.